# How to scroll to the top of the tableView in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My code does scroll to the top of the tableView view but I select a row and push to another ViewController and then come back and tap tab bar icon it doesn't scroll to the top. It scrolls upwards to some extent but doesn't work properly

extension UIViewController {

```
func scrollToTop() {
    func scrollToTop(view: UIView?) {
        guard let view = view else { return }

        switch view {
        case let scrollView as UIScrollView:
            if scrollView.scrollsToTop == true {
                if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -100 {
                    return
                }
                scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -150), animated: true)
                return
            }
        default:
            break
        }

        for subView in view.subviews {
            scrollToTop(view: subView)
        }
    }

    scrollToTop(view: view)
}


var isScrolledToTop: Bool {
    if self is PaymentsTabController {
        return true
    }
    if self is UITableViewController {
        return (self as! UITableViewController).tableView.contentOffset.y == 0
    }
    for subView in view.subviews {
        if let scrollView = subView as? UIScrollView {
            return (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

}

extension MainTabBar: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard let viewControllers = viewControllers else { return false }
    if viewController == viewControllers[selectedIndex] {
        if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            guard let topController = nav.viewControllers.last else { return true }
            if !topController.isScrolledToTop {
                topController.scrollToTop()
                return false
            } else {
                nav.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            return true
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: Using scrollToFirstRow doesn't work because I want to jump to the navigation bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```swift
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

Comment: .bottom somehow works! It scrolls to the tableHeaderView as needed.
Is there a way to scroll further such that the search bar in the nav bar becomes visible?

Comment: Have you tried making searchController active ? `searchController.isActive = true`

Answer (score 1):

For swift4 try -

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
```

Instead of

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -150), animated: true)
```

Comment: I tried so. It doesn't work :/ 
It scrolls a lit bit to the top only.